# OpenMP Performance Issues with Matrix Multiplication

Tags: c, openmp

I am  having issues with the performance using OpenMp. I am trying to test the results of a single threaded program not using OpenMP and an app using OpenMP. By looking at results online that are comparing matrix chain multiplication programs the openMP implementation is 2 to 3 times as fast, but my implementation is the same speed for both apps. Is the way I am implementing openMP incorrect? Any pointers on openMP and how to correctly implement it? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main( int argc , char *argv[] ) 
{
   srand(time(0));
   if ( argc != 2 )
   {
      printf("Usage: %s <size of nxn matrices>\n", argv[0]);
      return 1; 
   }

   int n = atoi( argv[1] );
   int a, b;
   double A[n][n], B[n][n], C[n][n];
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("/home/mkj0002/CPE631/Homework2/ArrayTry/matrixResults", "w+"); //For the LeCASA machine

   for(a = 0; a < n; a++)
   {
       for(b = 0; b < n; b++)
       {
          A[a][b] = ((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);  //Number between 0 and 1
          A[a][b] = (double)rand();         //Number between 0 and RAND_MAX
          B[a][b] = ((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);  //Number between 0 and 1
          B[a][b] = (double)rand();         //Number between 0 and RAND_MAX
          C[a][b] = 0.0;
       }
    }

    #pragma omp parallel shared(A,B,C)
    {
        int i,j,k;
        #pragma omp for schedule(guided,n)
        for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {
                double sum = 0;
                for(k = 0; k < n; ++k)
                {
                    sum += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
                }

                C[i][j] = sum;
                fprintf(fp,"0.4lf",C[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    if(fp)
    {
        fclose(fp);
    }
    fp = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) Don't perform I/O inside your parallel region. You'll see instantaneous speedup when you move that out and write many `C` variables simultaneously to file.

(2) After you've done the above, you should then change your scheduling to `static` because each loop will be doing the exact same amount of computations and there's no longer a need to incur the overhead from fancy scheduling.

(3) Furthermore, to better utilize caching, you should swap your `j` and `k` loops. To see this, imagine accessing just your `B` variable in your current loops.

```
for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
{
    for(k = 0; k < n; ++k)
    {
        B[k][j] += 5.0;
    }
}
```

You can see how this accesses B as if it was stored in Fortran's column-major format. More info can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). A better alternative is:

```
for(k = 0; k < n; ++k)
{
    for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        B[k][j] += 5.0;
    }
}
```

Coming back to your example though, we still have to deal with the `sum` variable. An easy suggestion would be storing the row of current `sum`s you're computing and then saving them all once you're done with your current loop.

Combining all 3 steps, we get something like:

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(A,B,C)
{
    int i,j,k;
    double sum[n]; // one for each j

    #pragma omp for schedule(static)
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            sum[j] = 0;

        for(k = 0; k < n; ++k)
        {
            for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {
                sum[j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }

        for(j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            C[i][j] = sum[j];
    }
}

// perform I/O here using contiguous blocks of C variable
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**: As per @Zboson's suggestion, it would be even easier to simply remove `sum[j]` entirely and replace it with `C[i][j]` throughout the program.

Comment: Swapping the `j` and `k` loops has two other major advantages besides better cache usage that I only thought of recently. First it has no dependency chain so you don't need to unroll the loop. Second because it does not have a dependency chain you also don't need to use associative math to vectorize the loop i.e. you only need `-O3` instead of `-Ofast` or `omp simd`.

Comment: BTW, why did you use `sum[j]`? Why not just use `C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]`?

Comment: @Zboson Can you further explain what a dependency chain is and how it relates to loop unrolling? Or provide a link? I've never heard of this term used anywhere outside of software dependencies.

Comment: @Zboson Also, It was 3am. You're correct - replacing `sum[j]` with `C[i][j]` is just as good. I was just copying OP's structure and didn't think it through fully.

Comment: For dependency chains see Section Chapter 11 (pages 103-105 currently) of Agner Fog's [Optimizing C++ manual](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf) particularly example 11.2a and 11.2b.

Comment: This is one of the problems with GCC currently. For reductions which are dependency chains GCC does not unroll the loop. Clang unrolls four times. OpenMP does not offer any solution for this either which is one reason why I find `omp simd` effectively useless. If `omp simd` offered a feature to unroll the loop it would suddenly become very interesting to me. But the advantage of looking over `j` instead of `k` as you have done is that it avoids this issue and GCC in my experience does a very good job without dependency chains.

Comment: Thanks, this increased the timing greatly. The changes increased my performance almost 10 fold with OpenMP.